# What are the full requirements to get a best buddy in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Everything I can find says that a Pokemon should become a Best Buddy once it has earned 300 hearts.

This Pokemon has 621 hearts and still isn't a Best Buddy.  So what are the other requirements for it to become a Best Buddy?

[image: Why isn't this Pokemon a Best Buddy?]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second menu on the buddy screen shows the number of *activities* done with your buddy, not the number of  *hearts*. It counts every interaction you’ve done with your buddy, including the ones that don’t result in a heart.<sup>1</sup>

So while you have done 621 activities with your buddy, the number of hearts hasn’t reached the 300 heart requirement.

<strike>Unfortunately (at the time of writing) there is no way to see the total number of hearts your buddy has acquired.</strike>

In some update since this posts submission, you can view how many hearts you have left until the buddy’s next friendship level. By viewing your buddy and clicking on the hearts, it’ll tell you when you are on the buddy’s current friendship level

[image: mewtwo showing remaining hearts]

---

<sup>1</sup> To easily test and confirm this, go to your buddy, check the number of snapshots, and then spam taking snapshots of your buddy. While you only received 1 (or 2) hearts, the number increased by the number of snapshots taken.